# Matlab Comparison Tool NaN values

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison, mat-file

I am trying to compare two .mat files using the Matlab Comparison Tool. In the comparison result the NaN values are highlighted meaning they are different (even though they are not). How can one handle the NaN values when using the Matlab Comparison Tool.

[image]

Comment: If all you want to do is know whether contents of two mat-files are equal, `a=load('file1.mat'); b=load(`file2.mat`); bothAreSame = isequaln(a,b)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Try [isnan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html).

```
   label = false(size(data)); 
   different =  true;
   label(isnan(data)) = different
```

You can also use `eq`:

```
b=[1 2;nan 4];
 a=[1 2;nan 4];
 eq(a,b)

 >>  1     1
     0     1
```

Comment: That would mean I'll have to identify the data that is affected and label them. I thought there would be an easier way from the Matlab comparison tool.

Answer (score 4):

`NaN` is by definition "not a number". Quoting the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/nan.html),

> A NaN is obtained as a result of mathematically undefined operations like 0.0/0.0  and inf-inf.

Therefore, mathematically speaking, **equality is not even defined** between NaN's. For example; trying to compute 0/0 gives NaN, as does 0/0+1. Would you say 0/0 and 0/0+1 are equal? Would you say they are different? Neither: 0/0 and 0/0+1 simply don't exist.

Programmatically, on the other hand, `NaN` is a well defined "value", as is equality between `NaN`'s: namely, `NaN` is always unequal to `NaN`. The rationale of this behaviour is probably the fact that mathematically NaN is undefined, and so it can't be equal to itself.

Comment: Sorry to nit-pick, but equality *is* defined between NaN's: the definition is that NaN is not equal to NaN. The expression `nan == nan` has a perfectly well-defined value, which is `false`.

Comment: @SamRoberts You're right. In Matlab it _is_ defined, although mathematically it would be undefined because the objects it applies to are non-existent. I have updated my answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm going to have to nit-pick again, I can't help myself. It's not MATLAB (or MathWorks) that does the defining, it's the IEEE standards for floating point arithmetic. Since this document is authored by mathematicians and is a consensus among them, equality between NaNs is *mathematically* defined.